# Compiler optimization for x86_64 object code

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, x86-64

I disassembled cpumask_next_and for debugging and found a difference between objects for desktop and server machine.

The desktop kernel has a sequence of callq - cmp - mov -jge,
but the server kernel callq - cmp - jge - mov.

I only guess is is because of the difference of the processor architecture or pipeline.

Why are this different code generated exactly?

```
<blink>
(gdb) disassemble cpumask_next_and
...
   0xffffffff8140aa9a <+42>:    callq  0xffffffff8141cd90 <find_next_bit>
   0xffffffff8140aa9f <+47>:    cmp    0x8b97e3(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffff81cc4288 <nr_cpu_ids>
   0xffffffff8140aaa5 <+53>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0xffffffff8140aaa7 <+55>:    jl     0xffffffff8140aa80 <cpumask_next_and+16>
   0xffffffff8140aaa9 <+57>:    pop    %rbx
   0xffffffff8140aaaa <+58>:    pop    %r12
   0xffffffff8140aaac <+60>:    mov    %edi,%eax
   0xffffffff8140aaae <+62>:    pop    %rbp
   0xffffffff8140aaaf <+63>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
</blink>

<blink>
...
   0xffffffff813fb58d <+29>:    callq  0xffffffff8140d4a0 <find_next_bit>
   0xffffffff813fb592 <+34>:    cmp    0x8c6b30(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffff81cc20c8 <nr_cpu_ids>
   0xffffffff813fb598 <+40>:    jge    0xffffffff813fb5a7 <cpumask_next_and+55>
   0xffffffff813fb59a <+42>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0xffffffff813fb59c <+44>:    bt     %rdx,(%r12)
   0xffffffff813fb5a1 <+49>:    sbb    %edx,%edx
   0xffffffff813fb5a3 <+51>:    test   %edx,%edx
   0xffffffff813fb5a5 <+53>:    je     0xffffffff813fb580 <cpumask_next_and+16>
   0xffffffff813fb5a7 <+55>:    pop    %rbx
   0xffffffff813fb5a8 <+56>:    pop    %r12
   0xffffffff813fb5aa <+58>:    leaveq 
   0xffffffff813fb5ab <+59>:    retq   
</blink>
```

Comment: Perhaps the two kernels are configured differently. You should build them from source code, and understand precisely the command compiling that particular `cpumask_next_and` function. Your question seems too broad or unclear for me. And perhaps the two kernels have been compiled with different compilers or optimzations

Comment: I just wander why compiler generates different assembly code with the same C code. I knew some compiler optimization technique but I don't understand this case.

Comment: Because the compiler was invoked differently, or was different, or (most likely) because the preprocessed kernel code is different (since the two kernels have been configured differently)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the difference between uni-processor and multi-processor?

Comment: This looks like it was compiled with different compiler settings or a different abi. Especially the stack frame seems to be different.

Comment: Which kernel from which distro?  And why would you expect them to be the same?  The whole point of having two different kernel packages is that they're built with different config options.  The 2nd function is clearly testing something extra, with a bit-test.

Comment: @PeterCordes the difference is just how the branch is laid out. In the first code, the expected branch is the `jge` so `jl` jumps away to code not shown but presumably containing the same bit twiddling.

Comment: Thank you, Jester. You're right. I missed what edi is for.